# Generating a gaussian time series in python

Tags: python, time-series, gaussian

I have a homework problem to write an autocorrelation analysis program. After a lot of internet combing and effort, I have what I think is a decent program. The next part of the question is to test the program by analysing a bivariate gaussian time series. I know what this is mathematicaly/statistically, but i'm not quite sure how to generate it in python. My program is written such that it takes a .txt file and does the analysis from there. But how can I generate a 2 variable gaussian time series in python? I've tried using the following:

```
import numpy as np
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 100]]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000) #5000 points
print x,y #just to see if it works
```

but it returns an error of 'too many values to unpack'. When I remove to 5000, I get 2 values, as expected. I think im misunderstanding the mulitvariate_normal functions input variables, but i'm just so confused now. How would I rewrite this code to generate a time series that I can then analyse?

Comment: You're trying to assign 5000 values to 2 variables; `x` and `y`. Change to `values = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is fine up until the assignment part.
You are assigning a `(5000,2)` array to 2 values along the first axis, that won't work.

Try transposing the array before assigning.
`x,y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T`